# Get text between 2 processing instructions

Tags: xslt, xpath

My goal is to get all text, including text inside elements, between 2 processing instructions using xslt.

Input file is DITA having standard XML-based structure. There are 2 processing instructions I am searching for  `<?PI start?>` and  `<?PI end?>`. I search for text after `<?PI start?>` and before `<?PI end?>`. There can be just text or an element that has text in it.

**Input**

```
<concept id="testcase" >
  <title> Introduction</title>
  <conbody>
    <p>
      <p>text01</p>
      <?PI start 1?> text02 <?PI end  1?>
      <b>   text03   </b> 
      <?PI start 2?> text04 text05 <?PI end  2?> text06
      <?PI start 3?> text07 <?PI end  3?>
    </p>
    <p>
      <?PI start 4?>text11 <?PI end 4?>
      <?PI start 5?><b>text12</b><?PI end 5?>
      <?PI start 6?> text13<?PI end 6?>
    </p>
  </conbody>
</concept>
```

My approaches were:

- match  `<?PI start?>`, and try to get `following-sibling` until I will get to the `<?PI end?>`. Problem is there is no break for a loop in xslt as well as there is no way to change the value of variable, so I don't know how to stop.

**xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="//processing-instruction('PI')[contains(.,'start')]"> 
    
  <xsl:variable name='text1' select="following-sibling::text()[preceding::processing-instruction('PI')[1][contains(.,'start')]][following::processing-instruction('PI')[1][contains(., 'end ')]] "/>
  <xsl:variable name='text2' select="following-sibling::*[preceding::processing-instruction('PI')[1][contains(.,'start')]][following::processing-instruction('PI')[1][contains(., 'end')]]/text() "/>
  <xsl:variable name="text" select="concat($text1,$text2)"/>
    
  <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**output**

```
<concept xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" id="testcase">
  <title> Introduction</title>
  <conbody>
    <p>
      <p>text01</p>
       text02 <?PI start 1?> text02 <?PI end  1?>
      <b>   text03   </b> 
       text04 text05 <?PI start 2?> text04 text05 <?PI end  2?> text06
       text07 <?PI start 3?> text07 <?PI end  3?>
    </p>
    <p>
      text11 text12<?PI start 4?>text11 <?PI end 4?>
       text13text12<?PI start 5?>
      <b>text12</b><?PI end 5?>
       text13<?PI start 6?> text13<?PI end 6?>
    </p>
  </conbody>
</concept>
```

- match text or any element that has  `preceding-sibling` `<?PI start?>` and `following-sibling` `<?PI end?>`.

**xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="//processing-instruction('PI')[contains(.,'start')]"> 
  <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*">  
    <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>  
  </xsl:for-each>
  
  <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::text()">  
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
  </xsl:for-each>
  
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**output**

```
<concept xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" id="testcase">
  <title> Introduction</title>
  <conbody>
    <p>
      <p>text01</p>
         text03    text02 
       
       text04 text05  text06
       text07 
    <?PI start 1?> text02 <?PI end  1?>
      <b>   text03   </b> 
       text04 text05  text06
       text07 
    <?PI start 2?> text04 text05 <?PI end  2?> text06
       text07 
    <?PI start 3?> text07 <?PI end  3?>
    </p>
    <p>
      text12text11 
      
       text13
    <?PI start 4?>text11 <?PI end 4?>
      text12
       text13
    <?PI start 5?>
      <b>text12</b><?PI end 5?>
       text13
    <?PI start 6?> text13<?PI end 6?>
    </p>
  </conbody>
</concept>
```

Problem is that it matches even the elements that are not between 2 processing instructions. For example `text03` from below, as technically it does have   `preceding-sibling` `<?PI start?>` and `following-sibling` `<?PI end?>`:

```
 <?PI start 1?> text02 <?PI end  1?>
 <b>   text03   </b> 
 <?PI start 2?> text04 text05 <?PI end  2?>
```

XSLT version: 1.0

XSLT processor: Saxon-HE

I will appreaciate any input, ideas and sugesstions

Comment: Which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use? In XSLT 2/XPath 2 with operators `<<` and `>>` and `for-each-group group-starting-with/ending-with` there are good tools to handle such cases, in XSLT 1 it gets a bit akward to use keys or sibling recursion.

Comment: Also as you want to "loop" and "break", XSLT 3 with `xsl:iterate` allows that kind of.

Comment: XSLT version: 1.0
XSLT processor: Saxon-HE
@MartinHonnen

Comment: Saxon HE supports XSLT 3 (since version 9.8) or XSLT 2 in earlier versions so it sounds odd to tell us you use Saxon HE but XSLT version 1.0. Anyway, if you use Saxon HE, independent of the `version` you declare, you can use `for-each-group group-starting-with` and nest a `for-each-group group-ending-with` to solve that, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PIs are always siblings then doing

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('PI')[starts-with(.,'start')]"> 
  <xsl:variable name="end-pi" select="following-sibling::processing-instruction('PI')[starts-with(., 'end')][1]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="nodes-before-end"
    select="following-sibling::node()[. &lt;&lt; $end-pi]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

should suffice to select the nodes between the two PIs. Output them as needed, I couldn't quite tell where/how you want to output them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you asked for, but maybe it will be useful.

I have this code that does almost exactly the same thing you asked for with minor difference: if the content of the node between 2 processing instructions is a collection of white-spaces or the text of a node between 2 processing instructions is a collection of white-spaces, it replaces them with empty nodes.
I am using pythons standard library, no need to install anything additional. Just make sure to run with python3(I run it with python3.6, but any python3+ should be fine)

```
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom import Node
import re


def get_all_processing_instruction_nodes(child_nodes: List):
    start_end_pairs = []
    current_pair = {}
    for index, node in enumerate(child_nodes):
        if node.nodeType == Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:
            if "start" in node.nodeValue:
                current_pair["start"] = {
                    "node": node,
                    "index": index
                }
            if "end" in node.nodeValue:
                if "start" not in current_pair:
                    raise ValueError("End detected before start")
                current_pair['end'] = {
                    "node": node,
                    "index": index
                }
                start_end_pairs.append(current_pair)
                current_pair = {}
    return start_end_pairs


def process_all_paired_child_nodes_recursively(node):
    pi_pairs = get_all_processing_instruction_nodes(node.childNodes)
    if pi_pairs:
        print(node.nodeName, "::", node.nodeValue)
        pprint(pi_pairs)
    for pair in pi_pairs:
        start_index = pair['start']['index']
        end_index = pair['end']['index']
        interesting_nodes = node.childNodes[start_index + 1: end_index]
        process_interesting_nodes(interesting_nodes)
    for child_node in node.childNodes:
        process_all_paired_child_nodes_recursively(child_node)


def process_interesting_nodes(interesting_nodes: List):
    for i_node in interesting_nodes:
        if i_node.nodeValue:
            i_node.nodeValue = re.sub(r"\s+", "", i_node.nodeValue)


def process_xml_file(input_file_path: str, output_file_path: str):
    document_node = minidom.parse(input_file_path)
    process_all_paired_child_nodes_recursively(document_node)
    with open(output_file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(document_node.toxml(document_node._get_encoding()).decode())
```

You can easily modify the process_interesting nodes function to do anything with the matched nodes(note that the plain text between 2 processing instructions is parsed as a Text node in python so you treat it as a regular node).

Hope this helps. I would also recommend you take a look at the python's xml lib, especially the minidom part (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html). Minidom module, unlike the regular xml parser, allows you to tread processing instructions and comments as regular nodes.